Pool heater safety switch
Pool heater is 230 V pool pump is 120 V. Is it OK to hook the safety switch to the pool pump even though it’s not 230v. is the safety switch a low-amperage relay to shut the heater off when the pump shuts off. 



We would need to see the diagram for the heater/pump. The safety switch for the pump water flow simply opens or closes the control circuit, along with other switches, that operates the coil for the heater contactor. It's a normally open pressure switch that closes when the pump is working. The control circuit can be 120 volts if a neutral is present or 240 volts if no neutral. The rating of the switch could be either voltage.

This is what I have

@John  Where is the safety switch? It won't be on the motor.  It should be included in the heater  on the water in pipe or water out pipe and already wired.

I posted pictures of the data sheets

@John  YES, but there's no safety switch shown on anything you posted.

Supposedly the safety switch is next to where you connect the power supply it says water pump. The heater won’t work unless there’s a connection to the water pump because if the water pump shuts off it will shut off the heater. Otherwise, I would have to put a jumper between the two connections for the heater to work.

Is there a schematic for this? Not trying to be difficult but I've never seen a separate safety flow switch that wasn't incorporated into the heating system. It's a fairly small switch that connects to a pipe and senses pressure when the pump is on.

I do not have a schematic. All I have is a user manual. I’m going to wait till I hook the pump up and see if it works without the water pump hooked up.

The labelling implies that the device in the final picture supplies 208-230V to the pump terminals. The boxed bit about 800W implies that it is the water pump power source. You would need to have a contactor with a 230V coil switching your 120V supply, or you can buy a 230V pump after frying your 120V pump by connecting it to this. Your call. The contactor is probably cheaper. I would not describe this arrangement as a "safety switch" at all.
